# How do I update the model in Angular.js?

Tags: angularjs

All the documentation I can find talks about the view automatically updating the model. However, using the example controller:

```
var phonecatApp = angular.module('phonecatApp', []);

phonecatApp.controller('PhoneListCtrl', function ($scope) {
  $scope.phones = [
    {'name': 'Nexus S',
     'snippet': 'Fast just got faster with Nexus S.',
     'age': 1},
    {'name': 'Motorola XOOM™ with Wi-Fi',
     'snippet': 'The Next, Next Generation tablet.',
     'age': 2},
    {'name': 'MOTOROLA XOOM™',
     'snippet': 'The Next, Next Generation tablet.',
     'age': 3}
  ];

  $scope.orderProp = 'age';
});
```

Within JavaScript, how would I (for example) change phones to an empty array? Basically I would like to do

```
$scope.phones = [];
```

(and have the view update automatically) but I can't figure out how to 'get to' the phones variable

Comment: You can use $scope.phones = []; anywhere in the javascript and your view will update automatically.

Comment: do you mean from an outside `$scope` or what? this is way too vague to even answer. what are you hoping to accomplish, specifically?

Comment: define something on your view like `<div ng-click="clearPhones()">empty phones</div>` then in controller define the clearPhones() like `$scope.clearPhones = function(){$scope.phones=[]}`

Comment: -1 to vote a bad answer as the proper one, and ignoring the comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're just trying to empty the array, then inside of that controller add a function to clear the array. Then use a directive to call the function. Example:

JS:

```
$scope.clearPhoneData = function() {
    $scope.phones.length = 0;
};
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-click="clearPhoneData()">Clear</div>
```

If you're trying to access the data from outside of this controller, then what you really want to do is set up a `service` that retrieves the phone data and makes it available to `controllers` that use the `service`. Then your `controller` uses the `service` as a `dependency` and you do something like:

```
$scope.$watch(function() {
    return phoneService.phones;
}, function(newData) {
    $scope.phones = newData;
});
```

It's really unclear what you want, but I implore you not to use `$scope.$apply()` when it's unnecessary.

Here is a plunkr that should help you: http://plnkr.co/edit/LwvZCz941CX9BGMqRhXe?p=preview

It shows the implementation of a `service` and how you can use it to access data across multiple controllers, clear the data, etc.

Comment: surely, glad to be of service. hopefully the example incites some imaginative thinking.